# Retrieve USB device information for drive which provides specific mount point

Tags: linux, c, c++

I am writing a C/C++ tool which needs to do the following:

1. Detect when a new mount point has been mounted. ✔
2. Find out which (USB) device provides this mount point. ❓
3. Get the USB vendor ID and product ID of this device. ✔ - libusb

I am unsure of how to do task 2, using the interfaces provided by GNU/Linux. Note that I'm not interested in using any command-line tools - I'm writing an application and need to use OS interfaces.

I have thus far considered using `/proc/{pid}/mountinfo` (which is what I use to check whether the mounts have changed), but it doesn't seem to allow me to trace which device provides this mount point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using udev, [libudev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/libudev.html) can be a good option. Udev is the subsystem of linux that is responsible of automatically creating device nodes when a new device is inserted to the system. With udev you can also monitor new devices as they are inserted to the system and get all the info that you want. It provides nice functions such as the "udev_device_get_sysattr_value" with which you can query any property that you want and gets its value easily.

In order to see what properties are available through udev you can use the udevadm utility like this:

> udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/your_device_node

Also you can find some sample code [here](https://gavv.github.io/articles/libudev-usb/) and [here](https://github.com/robertalks/udev-examples).

Comment: Together with the answer from dirkt, I think I can figure this out now - thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut Happy that it helped, since both posts were helpful it will be a good idea to accredit us then ;)

Comment: I had already upvoted both of your answers, but due to my low reputation, they are not publicly visible. Also, it was too early to accept an answer at the time.

Answer (score 2):

`/proc/{pid}/mounts` shows the device. Get major and minor id, then  `/sys/dev/block/{major}:{minor}` is a symlink to the USB device.